# Double level embed in Python Eve

Tags: python, eve

As far as i understand, Python Eve does not support a double level embed, can you confirm?

To better explain, given a document `A` referring to a document `B` referring to a document `C`, it is not possible to have `A` documents served by Eve with `C` embedded, right?

I think that this is not possible, since also in the [docs](http://python-eve.org/features.html#embedded-resource-serialization) says the following:

> We *do not* support multiple layers embeddings

Comment: It seems like your question is already answered. What are you asking of the community?

Comment: I am asking for confirmation. Maybe someone is very confident with the code, or she has some experience with this problem. I agree that this may seem silly, i would not be surprised if the question will be closed

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work. I have tried it. The settings.py file will show you double embedding that i've tried and it doesn't work.

```
import os
from schemas.subjects import subject_schema
from schemas.units import units_schema
# We want to seamlessy run our API both locally and on Heroku. If running on
# Heroku, sensible DB connection settings are stored in environment variables.
# MONGO_URI = os.environ.get('MONGODB_URI', 'mongodb://user:user@localhost:27017/evedemo')
MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGO_PORT = 27017
MONGO_DBNAME = 'test'

# Enable reads (GET), inserts (POST) and DELETE for resources/collections
# (if you omit this line, the API will default to ['GET'] and provide
# read-only access to the endpoint).
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']

# Enable reads (GET), edits (PATCH) and deletes of individual items
# (defaults to read-only item access).
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']

# We enable standard client cache directives for all resources exposed by the
# API. We can always override these global settings later.
CACHE_CONTROL = 'max-age=20'
CACHE_EXPIRES = 20

# Our API will expose two resources (MongoDB collections): 'people' and
# 'works'. In order to allow for proper data validation, we define beaviour
# and structure.
people = {
    # 'title' tag used in item links.
    'item_title': 'person',

    # by default the standard item entry point is defined as
    # '/people/<ObjectId>/'. We leave it untouched, and we also enable an
    # additional read-only entry point. This way consumers can also perform GET
    # requests at '/people/<lastname>/'.
    'additional_lookup': {
        'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
        'field': 'lastname'
    },

    # Schema definition, based on Cerberus grammar. Check the Cerberus project
    # (https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus) for details.
    'schema': {
        'id':{'type':'integer','required':True},
        'firstname': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minlength': 1,
            'maxlength': 10,
        },
        'lastname': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minlength': 1,
            'maxlength': 15,
            'required': True,
            # talk about hard constraints! For the purpose of the demo
            # 'lastname' is an API entry-point, so we need it to be unique.
            'unique': True,
        },
        # 'role' is a list, and can only contain values from 'allowed'.
        'role': {
            'type': 'list',
            'allowed': ["author", "contributor", "copy"],
        },
        # An embedded 'strongly-typed' dictionary.
        'location': {
            'type': 'dict',
            'schema': {
                'address': {'type': 'string'},
                'city': {'type': 'string'}
            },
        },
        'born': {
            'type': 'datetime',
        },
    }
}

works = {
    # if 'item_title' is not provided Eve will just strip the final
    # 's' from resource name, and use it as the item_title.
    #'item_title': 'work',

    # We choose to override global cache-control directives for this resource.
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,

    'schema': {
        'title': {
            'type': 'string',
            'required': True,
        },
        'description': {
            'type': 'string',
        },
        'owner': {
            'type': 'objectid',
            'required': True,
            # referential integrity constraint: value must exist in the
            # 'people' collection. Since we aren't declaring a 'field' key,
            # will default to `people._id` (or, more precisely, to whatever
            # ID_FIELD value is).
            'data_relation': {
                'resource': 'people',
                # make the owner embeddable with ?embedded={"owner":1}
                'embeddable': True
            },
        },
    }
}

interests={
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,
    'schema':{
        'interest':{
            'type':'objectid',
            'required':True,
            'data_relation': {
                'resource': 'works',
                # make the owner embeddable with ?embedded={"owner":1}
                'embeddable': True
            },
        }
    }
}

# The DOMAIN dict explains which resources will be available and how they will
# be accessible to the API consumer.
DOMAIN = {
    'people': people,
    'works': works,
    'interests':interests,
}
```

The end-point: 
http://127.0.0.1:5000/works?embedded={"owner":1} works

http://127.0.0.1:5000/interests?embedded={"interest":1}&embedded={"owner":1}  doesn't return the desired result.